# Filling page with a TikZ grid? Using modulus on variables?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm working on a document that looks great on A5 paper.  I need to modify it so it also will look great on half-letter paper (8.5" x 5.5").  Everything works fine with one exception - there are some grid pages that I can't get to line up.  Here is a sample grid page:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{a5paper}
\geometry{portrait}
\geometry{inner=18mm,outer=10mm,top=10mm,bottom=10mm}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\section{graph}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [step=0.5cm,very thin, gray] (0,0) grid (12.5,17.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which generates something like this:

[image]

But on half-letter this is too wide and goes off the right side of the page.  So I've modified it to be dynamic:

```
\section{graph}
\newdimen\spaceleft
\spaceleft=\dimexpr\textheight-\pagetotal-14pt\relax
% not sure why I need to subtract 14pt here.  Without it, the content is
% pushed down to the next page.
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [step=0.5cm,very thin, gray] (0,0) grid (\textwidth,\spaceleft);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But these values don't line up perfectly, leaving some empty grid cells:

[image]

If I put on my programmer hat, I want to take `\textwidth` and subtract `\textwidth % 0.5cm`.  Is this sort of thing doable in latex?  Is there a better way to fill a page with a grid?

The grid is just for doodling, so I don't need it to be an exact cell size/spacing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I put on my programmer hat, I want to take \textwidth and subtract
>   \textwidth % 0.5cm. Is this sort of thing doable in latex?

Sure thing - PGF (base layer of tikz) is your friend:

```
\pgfmathparse{\textwidth - mod(\textwidth,0.5cm)}
Textwidth: \the\textwidth\\
Modified width: \pgfmathresult pt
```

You have to `\usepackage{tikz}` for this to work but I have the strong feeling you are loading that anyways.

In total you could do something like this:

```
\newdimen\spaceleft
\spaceleft=\dimexpr\textheight-\pagetotal-14pt\relax
\pgfmathsetmacro{\gridWidth}{\textwidth - mod(\textwidth,0.5cm)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\gridHeight}{\spaceleft - mod(\spaceleft,0.5cm)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [step=0.5cm,very thin, gray] (0,0) grid (\gridWidth pt,\gridHeight pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I allowed myself applying the same calculation for the height. Note that it is essential that you manually add `pt` as the unit when using `\gridWidth` and/or `\gridHeight`. This produces
[image: Resulting grid]